# decrement the variable value by 1 in shell

Tags: shell, sh

what is the correct syntax to decrement/decrease the variable value by 1 in while loop using `/bin/sh` and not using `/bin/bash` script

I used following but does not work

```
 a=15
 ((a=a-1))   // not working 
 ((a--))       // not working
```

**EDIT 1**

```
i=0
a=[]
                    b=15
                    while [ $a == [] ] && [ "$i" -le 15 ]
                    do 
                      echo " Waiting ."
                      sleep 60s
                      ((i=i+1))
                      b=`expr $b- 1`
                      a=`some command`
                   
                    done
```

still getting following error

> sh: was: unknown operand /bin/sh: exit: line 186: Illegal number: -1

Comment: `sh` doesn't support arithmetic commands, so if you are executing your script with something like `sh tmp.sh`, then the result depends on which shell `sh` actually refers to. If `bash`, then it will still work, but if `dash`, you'll get an error that the command `a--` does not exist, because  `((...))` is interpreted as nested subshells, not a single arithmetic command.

Comment: There is no need to use `expr` in any POSIX-compliant shell; `b=$(( $b - 1 ))` works fine.

Comment: "not working" is not an accurate enough description of your problem to provide an exact answer.

Comment: Note that `[ $a == [] ]` has its own problems. It should be `[ "$a" = "[]" ]`, if you want to check if your variable contains the exact string `[]` in a way compatible with `/bin/sh`. `==` is an extension; the only POSIX-standardized string comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: Also, `$b- 1` is not `$b - 1`. Whitespace matters.

Comment: (Also, `sleep 60s` isn't guaranteed to work on non-GNU platforms; use just `sleep 60` for better compatibility).

Comment: ...also, don't use backticks. `$( )` is superior in every way (nests better, doesn't change how backslashes and other backticks are interpreted within), and again, is POSIX-standardized.

Comment: ...backticks and `expr` are artifacts of what Bourne shell like in the 1970s. The POSIX.2 standard (specifying POSIX sh) came out in the early 1990s. 30 years of backwards compatibility should be enough for everyone; you don't need to write shell scripts that 50-year-old software can run.

Comment: The `((...--))` construct only doesn't work for `dash` which is the default on some Ubuntu containers I have around.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic substitution is spelled `$(( ))` and expands to the result. If you just need the side effect (e.g. increment), use it in a null command:

```
a=15
: $((--a))
echo $a
```

Note that shell arithmetic is integer only.

Comment: this is also not working

Comment: @user2315104 Yes it is working. It will set a to 14 and echo 14. You are doing something else wrong. "Does not work" is not a meaningful description. What is the error, if any? What did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: Works for me too. Love how concise the code is even though the use of colon makes it less readable. Unless you know that colon is just an alias for `true`. Or just use `a=$((--a))`.

Comment: Note that this works only with `bash` and not `sh`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ a=15
$ a=`expr $a - 1`
$ echo $a
14
```

Comment: still getting error . please see EDIT 1

Comment: `expr` is slow, inefficient, **not** part of the shell itself (but instead depending on a separate executable provided by your operating system) and generally shouldn't be used by anyone (for math; there are other non-math operations it provides that POSIX `sh` doesn't provide alternatives to, but for arithmetic the POSIX-standardized `$(( ))` syntax does everything `expr` can do but better).

Comment: @user2315104 the other solutions provided are much clean and should work.
in EDIT 1 there is a space issue "b=`expr $b- 1`"  should be  "b=`expr $b - 1`"

Comment: nothing is working for me , i tried all the options

Comment: @user2315104 , can you share the error message ?

Comment: @user2315104, if you just __say__ you tried all the options, but you don't __show us how__ you tried all the options, there could be a mistake (like a space in the wrong place in the example you showed) and we would have no way of knowing without you actually showing us the specific code and its specific output; so how could we possibly know how to fix it, when you aren't demonstrating your attempt with the specifics in place?